# Getting JNLP error: "exception: Unable to load resource:..."

Tags: java, jnlp

I'm brand new to JNLP. 
I've been trying to fix this for straight 2 days... I have no clue...
I've a dynamic web project in eclipse. And I wanted to append an Applet in html. It works fine, if I append it without using jnlp. But if I use jnlp, its throws exception...
Please help me....
Here is my package structure:

```
  DaaS
DaaS\WebContent
\WebContent\AppletToJS.html
\WebContent\appletToJS.jnlp
\WebContent\FirstApplet.jar
```

"FirstApplet.jar"  contains the Applet class - AppletToJS.java

Here is my `jnlp` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>     
<jnlp href="appletToJS.jnlp">
 <information>
    <title>Dynamic Tree Demo</title>
    <vendor>Dynamic Team</vendor>
 </information>
<resources>
    <!-- Application Resources -->
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />

    <jar href="FirstApplet.jar" main="true" />
</resources>
<applet-desc
     name="Applet To JS"
     main-class="acid.AppletToJS"
     width="300"
     height="300">
 </applet-desc>
 <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

Here is my `html` file:

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>

<body>
  <script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
  <script>
    var attributes = { code:"acid.AppletToJS",  width:100, height:100} ;
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: "appletToJS.jnlp"} ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, "1.6");
  </script>

  <!-- <applet codebase="./jars" archive="FirstApplet.jar" Code="acid.appletToJS.class" width=200    Height=100></applet> -->

<p id="summary"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

while I run my html page I got following error:

```
 exception: Unable to load resource: http://localhost:8080/jars/FirstApplet.jar.
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://localhost:8080/jars/FirstApplet.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Caused by:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/jars/FirstApplet.jar
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://localhost:8080/jars/FirstApplet.jar
```

**http://localhost:8080/jars/FirstApplet.jar**

- I really don't understand where the hell "/jars" coming from???
- My project name is "DaaS" and my jar, html page and jnlp page are in same directory. And I'm running my html page on tomcat-7 server.